# Is it possible to delete a customer review that contains wrong information?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

We have an iPad app in the app store. Someone wrote a review that contains some false information about the app.

What can I do about this? Can I flag the comment so that Apple takes a look at it?

Comment: Let us know what happens if you do that.  Of course, some vendors may think *all* negative reviews are "wrong information".

Answer (score 9):

As of January 2015, you can in Itunes Connect:

- Sign in to Itunes Connect
- Go to ["Contact Us"](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/resources/page/contactus)
- Choose "App Store Questions"
- Choose "Customer Reviews"
- Choose "Specific Removal Request"
- Click on the ***2nd*** "contact us" link. A form should appear.
- Fill in the form and push "Submit"
- Wait for Apple to contact you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've successfully used this method a few times when the app store has failed to install the purchased app. In those cases, when the user contacted me, rebooting the system successfully installed the app, and contacting iTunes Connect, helped to remove negative reviews.

Comment: It seems this method is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 5):

You can't simply delete the review yourself, however you can flag it for review by Apple to be deleted.

Click on **Report a Concern** next to the review on the App Store, then select a reason for your flag, followed by comments:

[image]